# DTrace report uncorrect value when I tracing "malloc:return" in MacOS

Tags: c, heap-memory, dtrace

I want to get the return value of malloc, my DTrace command is:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'pid32519::malloc:return {printf("%p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %s\n",arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7,arg8,arg9,probefunc);}'
```

and the pid of provider is a tiny program as follow:

```
printf("%d\n",getpid());
getchar();
int cnt=50;
void* a = malloc(1000);
printf("%llx\n",a);
a = malloc(1000);
printf("%llx\n",a);
a = malloc(1000);
printf("%llx\n",a);
a = malloc(1000);
printf("%llx\n",a);
getchar();
return 0;
```

I found some documentation that say "arg1 holds return value", but the result is:

```
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  8  10499                    malloc:return f a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 60000000a malloc

  8  10499                    malloc:return f f 1 0 0 0 0 0 f00000000 60000000a malloc

  8  10499                    malloc:return f 10 1 0 0 0 0 0 f00000010 60000000a malloc

  8  10499                    malloc:return f 10 1 0 0 0 0 1000000000 f00000010 60000000a malloc
```

There is none of args equaled the return value of malloc and where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arg0` of the pid provider return probe contains the offset into the function of the particular return site; in this case `0xf`. The return values are suspicious which suggests that `malloc` is making a "tail-call" (a shortcut by which a function is called whose value will be returned by the calling function and allows a stack frame to be elided). We can see this in the disassembly output:

```
libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc:
0x7ff80c57f4d0 <+0>:  movq   %rdi, %rsi
0x7ff80c57f4d3 <+3>:  leaq   0x41a25b26(%rip), %rdi    ; virtual_default_zone
0x7ff80c57f4da <+10>: movl   $0x1, %edx
0x7ff80c57f4df <+15>: jmp    0x7ff800152a59            ; _malloc_zone_malloc
```

Instrumenting `pid$target::_malloc_zone_malloc:return` instead seems to produce reasonable return values.

FWIW this behavior is definitely confusing; during the development of DTrace we considered having tail-call returns have a special name, but discarded that as being *more* confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [DTrace Guide, FBT provider](https://illumos.org/books/dtrace/chp-fbt.html#chp-fbt):

> **20.2.2. return probes**
>
> While a given function only has a single point of entry, it may have
> many different points where it returns to its caller. You are usually
> interested in either the value that a function returned or the fact
> that the function returned at all rather than the specific return path
> taken. FBT therefore collects a function's multiple return sites into
> a single return probe. If the exact return path is of interest, you
> can examine the return probe `args[0]` value, which indicates the
> offset (in bytes) of the returning instruction in the function text.
>
> If the function has a return value, the return value is stored in
> `args[1]`. If a function does not have a return value, `args[1]` is
> not defined.

Note the use of `args[0]` and `args[1]` instead of `args0` and `args1`.  That might be significant to your dTrace implementation.

Comment: Thank for you suggestion about "args", but the function "malloc" returns an address  obviously. Why the "args[1]" is not defined?

Comment: @jin You're not using `arg[1]` - you're using `arg1`.  Those are not the same thing.

Comment: I have tried arg[1], and my system report an error as follow:

dtrace: invalid probe specifier pid80785::malloc:return {printf("%p\n",args[1]);}: in action list: index 1 is out of range for pid80785::malloc:return args[ ]